# Parsing strings to arbitrary enums in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, reflection, enums, kotlin-multiplatform

I was wondering whether it's possible to implement a function such as the following in Kotlin Multiplatform:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> parseToEnum(value: String): T {
    // ?
}
```

Basically, a function that takes the type of an Enum and a string and then returns the enum value of enum `T` that matches the passed string (`value`).

I know that it is possible in Java (and therefore in Kotlin/JVM) but I fear that there might not be a way to do this in common multiplatform code, because there's very little reflection data retained at runtime.

If there's a way to do this (or something similar in functionality), please let me know.

Using Kotlin 1.5.20 (or generally the newest version, I can update if necessary)

Comment: How do you intend to use this function? From what I can see, this will be something like `parseToEnum<MyEnum>("SOME_VALUE")`. Is there a reason why `MyEnum.valueOf("SOME_VALUE")` is not sufficient for you?

Comment: It's library code and the intent is that you can create a delegate which can at any given point parse an arbitrary string value to the enum value of the enum specified by the library user. I acutally found out that there's basically exactly this method in the standard library, so I'll just answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself, and it's fairly simple: There's a multiplatform stdlib function with exactly this signature:
[enumValueOf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-value-of.html).